# Why is my Wordpress Custom Post type not displaying in the Admin Menu

Tags: wordpress, admin, custom-post-type

I have this code working on a development site to create a custom post type.

When I copy it to the live site functions.php file it stops working? Specifically it doesn't show up in the admin menu on the left of the dashboard. What am I doing wrong?

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_manufacturer' );
function register_cpt_manufacturer() {
$labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Manufacturers', 'manufacturer' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'Manufacturer', 'manufacturer' ),
'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'manufacturer' ),
'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Manufacturer', 'manufacturer' ),
'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Manufacturer', 'manufacturer' ),
'new_item' => _x( 'New Manufacturer', 'manufacturer' ),
'view_item' => _x( 'View Manufacturer', 'manufacturer' ),
'search_items' => _x( 'Search Maufacturers', 'manufacturer' ),
'not_found' => _x( 'No maufacturers found', 'manufacturer' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No maufacturers found in Trash', 'manufacturer' ),
'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Manufacturer:', 'manufacturer' ),
'menu_name' => _x( 'Maufacturers', 'manufacturer' ),
);
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'hierarchical' => false,
'description' => 'Look up table to convert PL Serial to Ad Rotator Group',
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields' ),
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'has_archive' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'can_export' => true,
'rewrite' => true,
'capability_type' => 'manufacturer',
'map_meta_cap' => true
);
register_post_type( 'manufacturer', $args );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Changing the

```
'capability_type' => 'manufacturer', to
'capability_type' => 'post',
```

check https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type for more ifno

Comment: Thanks but that part refers to capabilities for users, specifically, by setting it to manufacturer I can then use User Role Editor to allow or disallow a role's access to that Menu item.

Comment: so you can add  'capabilities' => $cap abilities, after the capability_type, $capabilities is the array of the capabilities for this post type.

Comment: I am so sorry, you were right all along. This worked on the other site because I had built this up in parts. So prior to adding capability_type I had already added User Role Editor and created the user role Manufacturer. Then I added the 'capability_type' and 'map_meta_cap' after that.

Comment: So for the unaware, or stupid, like me, you need to create the user role as well otherwise you never see it!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the correct answer is to add the "capabilities" array under capability_type like so:

```
'capabilities' => array(
'publish_posts' => 'publish_manufacturers',
'edit_posts' => 'edit_manufacturers',
'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_manufacturers',
'delete_posts' => 'delete_manufacturers',
'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_manufacturers',
'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_manufacturers',
'edit_post' => 'edit_manufacturer',
'delete_post' => 'delete_manufacturer',
'read_post' => 'read_manufacturer'),
```

Next you will have to download a user role management plugin like "Members" found in the WordPress plugin repository. There you will assign these capabilities to the administrator and/or additional user roles. Only afterwards will it appear in the side menu.

[Mapping Meta Capabilities](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types)